# Search of a Schwartz Function with specific properties.

Tags: fourier-transform, schwartz-space

I want to find a Schwartz function $\varphi$ with the following properties
\begin{equation}
\varphi > 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \mathrm{supp}(\widehat{\varphi})\subset B_{R},
\end{equation}
where $B_{R}$ is a ball with radius R.

My first thought was something like $\varphi = g^{2}$ , because then $\widehat{\varphi} = \widehat{g}\ast\widehat{g}$. If $g$ is then a function where the Fourier Transform has $B_{\frac{R}{2}}$ , then $\mathrm{supp}(\widehat{g}\ast\widehat{g})\subset B_{R}$ but $g^{2}\geq 0$. So this don't work.
My next thought was to take the Gaussian Function and convolve it with a Schwartz function $f$ with compactly supported Fourier Transform. I know $f$ is analytic. But I'm not sure if the convolution from $f$ with the Gaussian is strictly positive?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function.

Comment: Yeah i know that this are schwartz Functions, but that does not help. Because why should the Fourier Transform of such Function be strictly positive?

Comment: By the conditions, $\hat\varphi$ must be a bump function: Since $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}$ we also have $\hat\varphi\in\mathcal{S}.$ Then $\hat\varphi\in C^\infty.$ Together with $\operatorname{supp}\hat\varphi$ having bounded support this implies $\hat\varphi\in C^\infty_c.$

Comment: Yeah that is right but the other condition ist that $\varphi> 0$ and this is i think the difficult thing.